# new lines not preserved on html - flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, newline

I have a json file crud app with flask, I do see the new lines "\n" on the json file or when I access it on python interpreter.

```
>>> for i in d:
...     if i['tag']=="flask":
...             i
...

'tag': 'flask', 'head': 'multiline test', 'data': 'app.jinja_env.keep_trailing_newline=True\n# line2'}
{'tag': 'flask', 'head': 'multiline test3', 'data': 'st1\r\nst2'}
```

However, when  on the html template \n are not preserved despite setting the keep trailing newline as true. Am I missing something here? I need to preserve the new lines on html - how can I do this ?

```
# app.py    
from jinja2 import Environment
    TEMPLATE_ENVIRONMENT = Environment(
        keep_trailing_newline=True)

# html
{%for j in d%} 
{{j['data']}} 
{%endfor%}
```

Below are the outputs I get on browser, note that the same dictionary shows a \n and the actual file shows \n too.

app.jinja_env.keep_trailing_newline=True # line2

st1 st2

Comment: `\n` is not a line separator for HTML

Comment: thanks a lot !! tried setting env.,tried a few other options, this finally worked - 
{% autoescape false %}
{{j['data']|replace("\n", "br /")
{% endautoescape %}

Answer (score 0):

Tried many options but this one worked - use autoescape & replace with a pipe

```
{% autoescape false %} 
{{j['data']|replace("\n", "br /") 
{% endautoescape %}
```